# React JS usRef() hook for header also affects footer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completely new to React and I have an App with the following structure in App.js:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the relevant code of my Header.js is:

```
function Header() {
const navLinksRef = useRef();
const toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen((prevMenuOpen) => {
      const navLinks = navLinksRef.current;
      const overlay = overlayRef.current;

      if (navLinks && overlay) {
        setIsTransitionEnabled(true);
        if (!prevMenuOpen) {
          // Open menu
          navLinks.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
          overlay.style.opacity = '1';

        } else {
          // Close menu
          navLinks.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
          overlay.style.opacity = '0';
        }
      }

      return !prevMenuOpen; // Toggle the menu state
    });
  };


  const closeMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(false);

    resetParameters()
      
    setIsTransitionEnabled(false);
  };

  const handleTransitionEnd = () => {
    setIsTransitionEnabled(false);
  };

  const resetParameters = () => {
    const navLinks = navLinksRef.current;
    const overlay = overlayRef.current;

    if (navLinks && overlay) {
      navLinks.style.transform = '';
      overlay.style.opacity = '';
    }
  };

return (
    <header className={`header ${menuOpen ? 'menu-open' : ''}`}>
      <div className="nav-container">
        <div className="menu-icon" onClick={toggleMenu}>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <nav
          ref={navLinksRef}
          className={`nav-links ${isTransitionEnabled ? 'transition' : ''}`}
          onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
        >
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/" onClick={closeMenu}>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/portfolio" onClick={closeMenu}>Portfolio</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about" onClick={closeMenu}>About</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div
          ref={overlayRef}
          className="overlay"
          onClick={toggleMenu}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

As you can see I am using `navLinks.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';` and `navLinks.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';` to modify the position of "navLinks". What I wanted to achieve here was to apply this transformation only to the navigation elements of the header. What actually happens is that my footer is affected as well. What am I doing wrong?

If it is of any help, this is the code of the footer:

```
function Footer() {
    return (
      <footer className="footer">
        <div className="footer-content">
          {/* Your other footer content */}
          <a
            href="https://www.instagram.com/julian.manke/"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            className="instagram-link"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} size="2x" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </footer>
    );
  }

export default Footer;
```

Edit: I am also going to provide the full code for the header.css, since there is a media link distinction between device sizes. Maybe that makes the problem more evident:

```
/* Header styles */
.header {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

/* Use media queries for responsive padding adjustments */
/* Smaller devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .nav-container {
        justify-content: center;
        /* Center the elements horizontally */
        position: relative;
        /* Ensure the nav container establishes a stacking context */
        z-index: 1;
        /* Higher z-index for the nav container */
    }

    /* Style the overlay */
    .overlay {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        /* Set initial opacity */
        opacity: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        align-items: center;
        /* Center the menu button horizontally */
    }

    .menu-icon span {
        height: 3px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .nav-links {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    .nav-links.transition {
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        /* Change color of navigation elements */
        font-family: 'Futura', sans-serif;
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 30px;
        /* Set the initial opacity */
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: flex;
        /* Maybe change for mobile vertical layout */
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        /* Adjust spacing of individual items */
        opacity: 1;
        /* Set the initial opacity */
    }
}

/* Larger devices */
@media (min-width: 769px) {

    .nav-links {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    /* Style for navigation elements within the <nav> element */
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 3rem;
        /* Adjust the initial padding as desired */
        /* Change the color of the navigation elements to black */
    }

    /* Navigation menu styles */
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
        /* Maybe change for mobile vertical layout */
        margin-right: 30px;
        /* Adjust spacing of individual items */
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
        /* Add a smooth transition for opacity changes */
        opacity: 1;
        /* Set the initial opacity */
    }

    nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        /* Change color of navigation elements */
        font-family: 'Futura', sans-serif;
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 22px;
        /* Set the initial opacity */
    }

    nav ul li:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
        /* Remove margin from the last element */
    }

    /* Apply opacity change on hover */
    nav li:hover {
        opacity: 0.3;
        /* Adjust the opacity value as needed */
    }

    nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
        /* Adjust text color of the navigation elements */
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Comment: your CSS styles for the transformations are not scoped to the specific elements you want to target. When you apply styles like translateX(0) and translateX(100%), they affect all elements that match the selector.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the transformations affect everything inside of the "<nav>" tag with the reference "navLinksRef"?

Comment: welcome. still if you are getting problem, let me know.

Comment: The problem is not evident from the code that you've posted. Most probably it has to do with the CSS `display` property (and everything that has to do with that) of the parent that holds both the header and footer.

Comment: "I am completely new to React" then be aware: `useRef` is not very beginner-friendly. It is in no small part an escape hatch for people who know what they're doing. Animations are a legit use case for it, but think carefully about whether or not you really need it here.

Comment: Good point, thanks for mentioning. I am just using it since I've read about it and did not find an alternative for my use case yet.

Comment: What is important is the CSS of the parent element (the `div.App` element). Here is an example of how `transform` affects elements when the parent has `display: flex` and `display: block` https://jsfiddle.net/ec24z3L5/